# Restoring screen brightness when terminating app in iOS

Tags: ios

I've seen the previous posts about the inability to ensure you can restore the screen brightness to the value it was before the user adjusted it within your app (i.e. capture the brightness level of the screen before your app loads and reset to that screen brightness before your app terminates or goes into the background). It appears that this might have been something that Apple did on purpose as to not make a dramatic change the user doesn't know about upon termination of the app. But it appears that Apple is somehow pulling this off with the Passbook app. Notice that when you launch into the Passbook app the screen brightness increases to allow scanners to read the bar codes better, but when you hit the home button and exit the Passbook app the screen brightness returns to what it was previously. If Apple can do this why can't we? Anybody know how the Passbook app does this?

Comment: Apple can do this because it's their platform.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very simple mechanism that was introduced sometime around iBooks 1.5+, and finally made available to use all with the addition of the `+[UIScreen brightness]` API in iOS 5.  Because it accepts a simple float from 0.0-1.0, storing it is a no-brainer, and restoring it can be done in any of the UIApplication delegate methods trivially.  In fact, I wrote a sample app (OOH, [Shiny](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54072935/Shiny.zip)) which restores screen brightness on launch, and saves it on exit.

Comment: Use it wisely, not many people like their apps propelling the screen brightness to 100%, or dimming it to an unreadable 5% on relaunch.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the opposite. I want to restore the screen brightness to what it was BEFORE the app was opened when the app is closed (for example, if the user of the app decides to crank the screen brightness all the way up in the app I want the brightness to return to what is was before entering the app when the user closes the app). The problem is that there appears to be no way to reliably ensure the app always restores the "saved" screen brightness value before terminating. Several people have guessed that Apple may be preventing devs from doing this to avoid sudden changes.

Comment: It's not quite the "opposite", so much as a modification of the sample application.  Remove the slider, establish a set value of brightness that you want in the defaults.plist, then put the restoration code in one of the termination methods.

Comment: The problem that others have encountered is that none of the termination methods work for restoring brightness. Even though they are called the brightness function isn't called, almost like Apple is disabling it behind the scenes.

Comment: Perhaps `sleep()`'ing for a second or two would get it to work.

Comment: I don't want to delay the termination of the app and I doubt Apple would approve of that anyway. Probably going to just have to either live with not being able to restore brightness or using the black box alpha trick to simulate brightness changes.

Comment: @user1609353 Whatever you decide, good luck.  And, Apple shouldn't ban your app for using `sleep();`, especially if it's for a small enough interval that the user won't notice.

Comment: Thanks, I may try that and see if it helps. Will work it out one way or another. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @1wayswim have you tried sleep(), I run in to a same problem but did not found any solution....please share your solution if you got any thing.... :) ;) thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
static CGFloat s_brightness = 0.5f;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    s_brightness = [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:s_brightness];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift

```
static var defaultBrightNess:CGFloat = 0.5;
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool 
{
        AppDelegate.defaultBrightNess = UIScreen.main.brightness;
        UIScreen.main.brightness = 1.0;
        return true
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UIScreen.main.brightness = 1.0
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(AppDelegate.defaultBrightNess)
}
```